# Real Sense Camera stopped working after upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04

Tags: lenovo, camera, ideapad

After upgrading my old Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04, my realsense camera stopped working.  Actually is not even detected.
My old laptop is an lenovo ideapad that has integrated realsense camera, and, as I've explained  it was working fine in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: There's no upgrade path from 16.04 to 22.04. What exactly do you mean by upgrade in this context? Please note that if you installed fresh then whatever was there before is irrelevant, immaterial and mentioning it like you did is misleading and counterproductive. If any other situation please describe it appropriately. And in any case edit your question and add the hardware information. The camera should be detected with `lspci` or `lsusb`.

Comment: Does `id` show that you're in the `video` group? Does `sudo lshw --class video` show it? [Edit] your Question to add information, don't use Add comment.